# Adding DBFS to environmental variable of a Databricks cluster to run a jar file

Tags: java, jar, databricks

I am trying to run a jar file on Databricks Jobs and to run it I had set environmental variable similar to the one I had to add to run on IntelliJ.
So I had changed it to the DBFS path expecting it to run.
[Added the DBFS path in environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLmuV.png)
But since the default folder is starts like '/databricks/driver/...' the DBFS path isn't getting detected.
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m4XL.png)

I would like to find a way to change the directory to start with 'dbfs/...' instead of '/databricks/driver..' so as to add the environmental variables.

Comment: how do you use this environment variables in your code or log configuration?

Comment: It's is added as under the advanced options when editing the Databricks Cluster. It's shown in the first image link that I had added.

Comment: But how it's used there? Or are you relying on existing log configs?

Comment: The log config is within the program that I am running. So if I am able to specify the log directory and the jar run is able to detect it, the logs will be generated in the file at the particular location which is stored in DBFS